# How to open/close a high (~110V) voltage circuit from a low voltage (5V) one with a transistor?

Tags: arduino, transistors, nixie

I'd like to turn on/off a Nixie tube from a 5V circuit system (Arduino). I've found a solution that uses transistors (1 pnp and 1 npn). Can't we do it with 1 singe transistor? What to consider? What's the best/simplest way? Thank you.

Comment: No, but even with two transistors is not such easy (110 VAC as from your title).

Comment: what if the two transistor circuit is the best and simplest way?

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Why do we need 2 transistors though?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/263719/what-kind-of-transistor-do-i-use-for-switching-high-voltage-with-a-microcontroll

Comment: Is the high voltage AC or DC?  Can use a single mosfet if it is DC.

Comment: Great!! It is DC.  How to? Ok, I'll google it. 

Comment: Maybe you need a high side switch, maybe you don't. Mirages sometimes appear in deserts and this is a question light on actionable information.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany has a good point. For more detailed comments/answers you should provide a schematic.